# access a variable declared on a separate JavaScript file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files the first one is an HTML file the other one is a javascript file. What I was trying to do was define a variable on the javascript file and access it on the Html side. Is it possible? A rough code is attached below but it doesn't work I get favColor is not defined error. thanks in advance.

JS Side

```
const favColor = "red"
```

Html side

```
<script src="pathtojsfile"></script>

<p id="insertHere"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = favColor
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn’t do that and keep all the JS logic in js file. You can put your code surrounded with script tag in js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is widely considered bad practice to work with global variables. To avoid it, you can make use of ECMAScript Modules, introduced back in 2015 with ES6/ES2015.

This allows your first Javascript, let's name it `colors.module.js` to `export` the variable:

```
export const favColor = 'red';
```

Then, in your script that needs to access this variable, you import it:

```
import { favColor } from '/path/to/js/modules/colors.module.js';
```

For that to work, you need your *importing* script to have `type=module` attribute, and the `import` must be done on top of your Javascript. The script you import *from* **does not need to be included in the page**.

Here's some helpful links to get you started with modules:

- [ES Modules Deep Dive](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)
- [Javascript Modules on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)
- [Flavio Copes' take on ES Modules](https://flaviocopes.com/es-modules/)

I've set up [a tiny github repo demonstrating this very basic usage of an ES module](https://github.com/franktopel/es-modules-test).

If modules are not an option, e.g. because you must support IE 11, or your build stack doesn't support modules, here's an alternative pattern that works with a single namespace object you attach to the global object `window`:

```js
// colors.module.js
window.projectNamespace = window.projectNamespace || {};
projectNamespace.colors = window.projectNamespace.colors || {};
projectNamespace.colors.favColor = 'red';
```

and in your page you access it from that name space:

```js
document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = window.projectNamespace.colors.favColor;
```

This way you have a single location to put all your globally accessible variables.

Comment: ```Cannot use import statement outside a module```@connexo

Comment: You need to **read** the post: *For that to work, you need your importing script to have type=module attribute*. `<script src="/path/to/my/javascript.js" type=module></script>` or `<script type=module> /* your js here */ </script>`

Comment: My bad didn't see that part. But I am getting error ```unexpected token 'export' ```. @connexo

Comment: Then you have something that alters/processes your `colors.module.js`, like a minifier or bundler. How to make your build chain work with modules is a different question. Feel free to ask a new question, describing in detail what you are using. Btw, what exactly is giving you that error?

Comment: My guess would be you're using `gulp` and something the like of `uglify.js`. Correct?

Comment: I had a minifier removed it and the error went away but I'm still getting var undefined. Can you think of any other reason why it might not work. @connexo

Comment: I'm setting up a small github repo for you, demonstrating it works.

Comment: Sorry, forgot two files required so you can reproduce the steps-to-run. `git pull` in your project folder, and you're good to go. You need `git` and `Node.js` installed properly; alternatively you can have any local webserver of your own host the two files (html and js).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231666/discussion-between-anon20010813-and-connexo).

Answer (score 2):

As the code is written in your example it should work fine. Just like my example here:

```html
<script>
  const favColor = "red";
</script>

<p id="insertHere"></p>

<script>
  document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = favColor;
</script>
```

But there can be a number of issues if the code is not like this. But the JavaScript code could just go in the same file. Try to separate the html from the JS like this (the code in the script element could be moved to it's own file):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    const favColor = "red";

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = favColor;
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="insertHere"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I'm also adding the eventlistener for DOMContentLoaded, so that I'm sure that the document is loded into the DOM.

Comment: I don't know why but I'm still getting var not defined. I have multiple separate js scripts loaded onto my HTML do you think that has something to do with it? script works fine when on the same page but when on a different file it doesn't work @chrwahl

Comment: @anon20010813 the code in comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/67285696/322084 should work perfectly fine. References to multiple js files. The order of the references is important.

Answer (score 1):

Where your variable is declared is not the problem *per se*, but rather the loading order of scripts.
If you want to make sure external scripts are loaded before you execute yours, you can use the `load` event of `window` object. It will wait until all resources on your page are loaded though (images, css, etc.)...

```js
const myvar = "Hey I'm loaded";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Document</title>
      <script>
          //console.log(myvar); //<- fails
          window.addEventListener('load', e => {
            document.querySelector('#insertHere').innerHTML = myvar;
          });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="insertHere"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can put all your code in js files, and they will be invoked in the order they are declared.

**Edit**
Given objections and more questions popping in the comments, I'll add this. The best and cleanest way to achieve this remains to put your code in a `.js` file of its own and put all your `<script>` tags inside `<head>`, with yours last, as it relies on others to run.

Then you can either add the attribute `defer` to your `<script>` or have everything wrapped in an event handler for `DOMContentLoaded` so that it gets run *after* the DOM is fully loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src='other1.js'></script> <!-- let's say this one declares myvar -->
      <script src='other2.js'></script>
      <script src='other3.js'></script>
      <script src='myscript.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="insertHere"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

myscript.js

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    document.querySelector('#insertHere').innerHTML = myvar;
});
```

Comment: First question I taught adding ```defer``` in the script tag when importing takes care of loading the script before DOM. second question how can I access the ```<p> ``` tag if I include my whole js in one file? @julien.giband

Comment: The scripts in the header section are executed before any scripts in the body section, unless you use async. So I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: The same way you would if the JS was in the script tag.

Comment: @anon20010813 first, `defer` does the exact opposite: it waits until the DOM is loaded before running the script. And second, you can access any part of the DOM from any javascript, provided it's already loaded when the script runs. So you should probably use `window.DOMContentLoaded` event

Comment: @Gerfried it's a runnable snippet, so maybe you could try running it before declaring it's wrong. And the script is wrapped in a handler for `window.load`, so it will run only after everything is loaded, as stated before the snippet. Maybe you should read too

Comment: Your script works, but your explanation is wrong - see the answer of @chrwahl

Comment: @Gerfried answers are open to everyone so please feel free to post your own

Comment: I don't know why but I'm still getting var not defined. I have multiple separate js scripts loaded onto my HTML do you think that has something to do with it?script works fine when on the same page but when on different file it doesn't work @julien.giband

Comment: @anon20010813 I don't. If some have the attribute `async` or `defer`, it may change the order in which they are loaded / evaluated though. The simplest way remains to keep your own script inside a js file of its own, import it last, and either tag it `defer` or wrap your code in an event handler for `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: @julien.giband - I rebuilt the sample of anon20010813 on my localhost (html + js) - it works - could you please do the same?

Comment: did you use separate files for html and js @Gerfried

Comment: @julien.giband - yes